# Combining categorical and continuous input features of different shapes to predict continuous variable

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have two types of input, one is continuous data with shape like (6000 x 3 x 3 x 256). The other is categorical / binary, a shape of (6000 x 1).

The dependent variable is continuous.

This is how I'm currently training my model for the continuous data:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)


model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001), input_shape=(3,3,256)))

model.add(Flatten()) # Fix input shape error

model.add(BatchNormalization()) # Fix predictions coming out all the same

model.add(layers.Dropout(0.6))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the model 
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])

# training the model 
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

I'm wondering how I can combine this with my other binary feature - do I make a model to predict a continuous variable from categorical and just concatenate with the model I have above?

**Edit**

I've been trying something like this but getting an error:

```
# Define input
colour_histogram_input = Input(shape=(3,3,256), name='colour_histogram_input')
contains_face_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='contains_face_input')

# Layers
colour_histogram = Dense(64,  activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(colour_histogram_input)
contains_face = Dense(64,  activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(contains_face_input)

# Concat
concatenated = concatenate([colour_histogram, contains_face])

# Output
output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(concatenated)

# Model
model = Model(inputs=[colour_histogram_input, contains_face_input], outputs=[output])
```

Error

```
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 3, 3, 64), (None, 64)]
```